# uiwebview is not working for Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview, swift2, xcode7

The code I was using for Xcode 6.4 to open a uiwebview doesn't load for Xcode 7 when starting simulator.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var webLaundry: UIWebView!


func loadWebPage(){
    let theURL = "http://www.google.com"
    let theRequestURL = NSURL (string: theURL)
    let theRequest = NSURLRequest (URL: theRequestURL!)
    webLaundry.loadRequest(theRequest)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loadWebPage()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

What should I change to fix this issue?

Comment: Can you explain what "doesn't work" means in this case?

Comment: The simulator just shows a white screen and the is no network connectivity in the debugger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is apple's new security requirement. app transport security in iOS 9 .

What you will need to do is:

1. in xcode 7  ,  in your project , find " Info.plist" , right click , open as " source code " .
2. put words below between last  and

`<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>
</dict>`

3. run your project
4. [Source](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/5857#5857)